# Live wallpaper onTouchEvent() fade animation/transition?

Tags: android, live-wallpaper, touch-event, transitiondrawable

I have created a live wallpaper. I would like for the onTouchEvent() to draw an animation or transition from one PNG file to another PNG file at the Touch Event location. So far I am able to draw one of the PNG files at the location but I have not been able to get the transition to work.

Here is the code I am currently using to attempt to animate the fade from one image to another:

```
void drawTouchPoint(Canvas c) {
        if (mTouchX >=0 && mTouchY >= 0) {
            TransitionDrawable td = new TransitionDrawable(new Drawable[] {getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pipe_logo), getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pipe_logo_blank)});
            td.setBounds(mTouchX, mTouchY, mTouchX + 100, mTouchY + 100);
            td.setCrossFadeEnabled(true);
            td.startTransition(3000);
            td.draw(c);
        }
    }
```

The code above only draws the pipe_logo image. I have tried reversing the order and then only the pipe_logo_blank image is drawn. I feel like I'm close on this and just missing something simple. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I have found many examples to use Animations but they all require a view such as an ImageView. In this case, because I am using a Live Wallpaper, I do not have a view available to use.